# Once checkbox is true, how do you make it false once clicked again? (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having trouble updating my boolean to be false again once clicked for a second time.

```
  def completed
    if @todo.update_attribute(:completed, true)
      flash[:success] = "Wowzers."
      redirect_to dashboard_path 
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Not so wowzers..."
      render :new
    end
  end
```

This is what I have currently, it sets my boolean to true once clicked but I'm not sure how to `if @todo.update_attribute(:completed, true, false)`thinking this would be like a toggle, true then false but it's not the case.

I have also tried

```
  if params[:completed] == 0
    @todo.update_attribute(:completed, true)
    flash[:success] = "Wowzers."
    redirect_to dashboard_path 
  elsif params[:completed] == 1
    @todo.update_attribute(:completed, false)
    flash[:success] = "Wowzers."
    redirect_to dashboard_path 
  end
```

But this doesn't save to my database (true or false).

My question here is; how can I toggle my checkbox true then false, rather than just true or false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic principle of logical negation is `!`, the `not` operator, is your friend:

```
@todo.update_attribute(:completed, !@todo.completed)
```

That will flip it back and forth.

Answer (score 2):

In HTML post requests, params are always passed as strings so `params[:completed] == 1` will always be false. You probably want `params[:completed] == '1'` or `params[:completed] == 'true'`.

Also, if you want to toggle a param, simply use the toggle action.

```
@todo.toggle(:completed)
```

Otherwise, to save based on inequality of your param use

```
if @todo.update_attribute(:completed, params[:completed] != '1')
  flash[:success] = "Wowzers."
elsif 
  flash[:error] = "Couldn't update completed status"
end
redirect_to dashboard_path
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 def completed
    if  @todo.update_attribute(:completed, params[:completed])
      flash[:success] = "Wowzers."
      redirect_to dashboard_path 
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Not so wowzers..."
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Comment: This is actually saving twice, you can simply do `if @todo.update_attribute(:completed, params[:completed])`

Comment: ohh yeah.. I completed confused by assign_attribute haha

Comment: Hah, yeah, I do that too sometimes.